# How to remove Firefox's enter-key with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

How can I remove the Firefox's enter-key as an image below with Javascript?

I add more "(" and ")" to my code and it works very well in IE, yet it seems not work in Firefox or Chrome browsers.

**Moreover, please tell me the differences between IE and Firefox which affect to my code.**

[image]

Here is my code:

**Javasript:**

```
// Extract the labels by adding "(" and ")"
labels[i] = txt1 + "(" + txt + ")";
...
var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
alert(str);
var res = str.replace(/(<br>)/g, '');
alert(res);
```

**JSFIDDLE**: **http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/L7vXL/**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking to remove the line break.

Do this:

```
// Extract the labels by adding "(" and ")"
labels[i] = txt1 + "(" + txt + ")";
...
var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
alert(str);
var res = str.replace(/\n/g, '');
alert(res);
```

`\n` is used to match the line breaks.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AmitJoki/L7vXL/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please tell me the differences between IE and Firefox which affect to my code.

Comment: @PMay1903, IE sucks. But your original code didn't work in my IE 11

Comment: @PMay1903, don't know but **your** original code didn't work in my IE

Comment: That's great. I will show you my code later if I still get problem. Anyway your code is perfect. Thank you again :-)

Comment: Glad to have helped :)